# C create Windows Taskbar Notification

Tags: c, windows, winapi, notifications

How do i create a Popup like this: [image: Popup]

I try `Shell_NotifyIcon()` but this only creates an image in the Taskbar and the Balloon function don´t work in Windows 10 anymore. Maybe i missed something but i don´t find any other function to do that.

Following is my setup:

```
NOTIFYICONDATAA dataa;
dataa.cbSize=sizeof(dataa);
dataa.hWnd=hWnd;
dataa.uID=0;
dataa.uFlags=NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE;
dataa.hIcon=LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_QUESTION);
strcpy(dataa.szTip, "Test1");
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &dataa);
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &dataa);
```

Comment: is this what you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/notification-area ?

Comment: you can [edit] your post

Comment: That looks to me like a [toast notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-notifications-overview)

Comment: If you use a balloon tooltip (`NIF_INFO`) then modern Windows turns it into a toast notification automatically.

Comment: I #define _WIN32_IE 0x0550, fill the szInfo array, and add NIF_INFO to uFlags and call it like above but no Notification will popup. @JonathanPotter

Comment: @Erz try sending `NIM_SETVERSION` after `NIM_ADD` to enable newer features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With following code i can create a Notification like this:

[image: Notification]

```
NOTIFYICONDATAA dataa;
    dataa.uTimeout          =       3000;
    dataa.uVersion          =       NIM_SETVERSION;
    dataa.cbSize            =       sizeof(dataa);
    dataa.hWnd              =       hWnd;
    dataa.uID               =       0;
    dataa.uFlags            =       NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_INFO;
    dataa.hIcon             =       LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WARNING);
    dataa.dwInfoFlags       =       NIIF_WARNING;
    strcpy(dataa.szTip, "Test1");
    strcpy(dataa.szInfo, "Test2");
    strcpy(dataa.szInfoTitle, "Test3");
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &dataa);
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, &dataa);
```

Thanks to Remy and Jonathan. This seems easier than the [toast notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-notifications-overview) option.
In my tests i can only change the Test2 and Test3 string. The title string i can not change, i think this do Windows. After running the .exe, the App name will used as title string.

To generate the Notification and use the struct like in code, **the Version must set** to

> #define _WIN32_IE 0x0650 //or other value above 0x600

before including shellapi.h.